# ./node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts (1689,12): Cannot find name 'Exclude'

Tags: angular, typescript, lodash

I had a development environment of a project working on my mac osx Mojave. However, due to memory RAM issues, I decided to downgrade to ma osx High Sierra. Now, I'm trying to deploy the project again but I'm facing the following issue

```
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts(1689,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.

1689         ): Exclude<TObject[TKey], undefined> | TDefault;
```

This is part of the script that tries to compile this part: `tsc ./src/app/+charts/index.ts --outFile ./shared/charts.js --module amd --pretty`. So, it uses global Typescript to compile it. I have installed globally the versions 3.4, 2.6, and 2.8, but in all of them I get the same error. Also, the correct node version for this project is 8, so I'm using 8.16.0 (which was the version I was using before formatting the computer).

This is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@covalent/core": "1.0.0",
    "@covalent/dynamic-forms": "1.0.0",
    "@covalent/highlight": "1.0.0",
    "@covalent/http": "1.0.0",
    "@covalent/markdown": "1.0.0",
    "@covalent/text-editor": "1.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "d3": "^4.9.0",
    "d3-format": "^1.2.0",
    "exceljs": "^0.5.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "9.10.0",
    "html-pdf": "^2.1.0",
    "libphonenumber-js": "1.0.24",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "2.21.0",
    "moment-range": "3.1.1",
    "ngx-currency": "^1.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "showdown": "1.6.4",
    "web-animations-js": "2.2.5",
    "webshot": "^0.18.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.30",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.110",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.36",
    "codelyzer": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.31",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.14",
    "prepend-file": "^1.3.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "3.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2",
    "watch": "^1.0.2"
  },
```

I've also tried to change the line `"@types/lodash": "^4.14.110",` to `"@types/lodash": "^4.14.121",` but that didnt work either. And, I'm not sure if it does make sense changing anything in the package.json, as I had this project working ok before I formatted my computer and downgraded the OS

So, what am I missing here? I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an issue with `@types/lodash` you can look up the issue here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33778

The solution seems to be to [downgrade `@types/lodash` to](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33778#issuecomment-473358843)

```
npm i -D @types/lodash@ts2.5
```

[or updating typescript](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33778#issuecomment-473661864)

```
typescript@~2.8
```